# Создание каталога и файла с кириллицей в именах

Tags: java, файлы, кодировка, кириллица

Как в Java создать каталог и файл с кириллицей в именах?
Например:

```
String f_name = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\Вася\\Пупкин\\";
new File(f_name ).mkdir();
new File(f_name + "Ибрагимович.txt");
```

Выдает ошибку: каталог не создан и, соответственно, системе не удается найти указанный путь.

Искал везде, многое опробовал но не помогает. Прошу вашей помощи!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы создать все необходимые родительские каталоги для заданного файла используйте [`File.mkdirs()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs())

```
new File(f_name ).mkdirs();
```

[`File.mkdir`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdir()) возвращает буллево значение: true если каталог создан, false — в противном случае. Результат нужно проверять во избежание недоразумений.

В данном случае скорее всего возвращается `false`, т.к. «Вася» не существует, а `mkdir` умеет создавать только один каталог.

Насколько я понимаю кириллица не связана с данной проблемой.

Comment: Вы абсолютно правы. Прошу прощения за свою невнимательность. И спасибо за столь развернутый ответ!

Comment: @SmallSani Пожалуйста! Ничего страшного, Ваш вопрос содержал достаточно информации, чтобы догадаться в чем проблема. Если проблема решена, то зачтите ответ (галка слева от ответа).